# No combining geom point with geom line in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I´m trying to get just one legend with shape that have the same color as the graph but it is just in black color:

```
type1    <-c("tmax","tmax","tmax","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmax","tmax","tmax","tmin","tmin","tmin") 
station1 <-c("Anda","Anda","Anda","Anda","Anda","Anda","Mach","Mach","Mach","Mach","Mach","Mach") 
date1    <-c(2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2003,2002,2003,2004,2002,2003,2004) 
meanTemp1<-c(15,16,15.5,5,7,8,13,14,12,9,9,7)

data11 <- data.frame(type1,station1,date1,meanTemp1)

plot1<- ggplot(data11, aes(x=date1, y=meanTemp1,group = station1,colour=station1,shape=station1)) +
        geom_line () + guides(colour=FALSE)+
        geom_point() + 
        xlab("year") + ylab("°C") + 
        labs(shape = "Station")+
        facet_wrap(~type1,scales = "free")+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60,hjust = 1))
plot1
```

[image: output plot]

How can I get the legend fill with the same color as the graph instead of "black"?

Comment: So why did you add `guides(colour=FALSE)` if in fact you want a color guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rename `shape` legend in `labs`, you also need to rename `colour` legends using the same name in order they get merge.

Instead of using `guides(colour = FALSE)`, you can pass in `geom_line`, the argument `show.legend = FALSE` to remove the colored lines in the legend:

```r
plot1<- ggplot(data11, aes(x=date1, y=meanTemp1, group = station1,
                           colour=station1,
                           shape=station1)) +
  geom_line (show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("year") + ylab("°C") + 
  labs(shape = "Station", colour = "Station")+
  facet_wrap(~type1,scales = "free")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60,hjust = 1))
plot1
```

[image]